# What happens in background when forwarding x11 through ssh?

Tags: user-interface, ssh, docker, x11, xserver

I'm trying to become familiar with what is actually happening behind the curtain when I have an xServer running on my host machine and then I connect to another machine using ssh, like so: `ssh -Y user@machine`. In this scenario, I would be using cygwin on Windows, with my `DISPLAY` environment variable set to `:0.0` and would run a GUI app once connected to the remote machine, which would show up on my host machine. A Mac would be using Quartz for the local xServer (sorry if this term isnt correct, but hopefully you know what I mean) and would use `ssh -X user@machine` instead of `-Y`.

The goal here is to have a Docker container that is simply responsible for installing and running a GUI application. I would run the Docker container on my host machine and the GUI would pop up on the host from the target.

I have already made this work through ssh and manually starting the GUI app once in the container. I just need to know how to configure this vanilla Linux machine (the Docker container) to forward the GUI. **I think understanding what the `ssh -Y` command is actually doing to set up the forwarding correctly is the missing puzzle piece I need.** I have a vague understanding of the existence of a `.Xauthority` file. I am not concerned at all about how secure the connection is. I'll worry about that after I get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### X application <-> X server

First, how does X application finds and connects to X server?

The application reads the `DISPLAY` environmental variable to find out how to connect to the X server. For example value `:0` means it should connect on unix socket in `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`, value `hostname:5` means to connect to TCP port `6005` of computer `hostname`.

The X server can be configured to request authentication from the applications. Typically when the X server is started as a part of user's session the cookie is stored in the `.Xauthority` file in user's home directory and is readable only by the user. By sending the cookie to the X server, the application proves that it has the permission to read the user's files and so has also permissions to see his display. (The file can be in different path set by environmental variable `XAUTHORITY`.)

### ssh forwarding

When you ssh to a server with `-X` or `-Y` parameter, the ssh will read the authentication cookie for your local X server and send it to the ssh server on the remote side.

On the remote side, ssh will create temporary authentication file with that cookie and point the `XAUTHORITY` variable to it. It will start listening on some local port (for example `6010`) and set the `DISPLAY` variable to point to it (for example `localhost:10`). If you start any graphical application in that session, it will connect to the ssh (thinking it's the X server) which will tunnel it back to the local side.

On the local side, the ssh forwards any tunneled connection into the local X server. (Which it found using the `DISPLAY` variable.)

Difference between `-X` and `-Y`: A malicious root on the remote machine could read the cookie from the cookie file in there and use it to connect back to your X server. If you use `-X` ssh uses X server's security extension to deny some abilities from the application (like taking screenshots or grabbing keyboard). But some applications may need those to work, so if you trust the server, use `-Y`.

### Alternative

By the way if the network is completely trusted (like the virtual network between your machine and virtual machine), you can omit ssh completely. You can set the `DISPLAY` variable so that the remote application will connect to your local X server (Quartz) over TCP. You just have to enable listening on TCP in your Quartz and set the cookies on both sides. This looks like reasonable tutorial:
http://oroborosx.sourceforge.net/remotex.html

Comment: I know this is necroposting, but I want to say in the era of docker, This is the secret sauce ```On the remote side, ssh will create temporary authentication file with that cookie and point the XAUTHORITY variable to it.```